# Android Layout suggestions required

Tags: android, layout

I am building an Android app in which there is a list of items in a gridview, and I would like the user to select any of them.I do not want to use a radio group/radios, but an icon and a name of the item next to it.

Once the user has selected something, I have three buttons at the bottom, back, cancel and set as default.

The problem is arranging this stuff so that it appears fine on a landscape mode as well as portrait mode.

Can someone suggest a good layout skeleton?

Here is the Android layout file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<GridView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/GridView01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
   android:layout_height="370dip"    
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"    
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
    android:gravity="center">
</GridView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Back  "
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/GridView01"

>
</Button>

<Button
android:id="@+id/setDefault"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Set as Default  "
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel"
android:layout_below="@+id/GridView01"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/cancel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Cancel  "
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/GridView01"
>
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Relative Layout,[Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to know how to use Relative Layout.

Comment: Hello Sankar,I have used absolute layout. Request you to to help me more with the layout itself.